# How to search the skill is exist in the Resume or not using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can any body help me

```
Problem: I Have a "User" table 

USER
-------------------------------
uid   | Uname | Resume | skill
-------------------------------
1       bla     a.doc     php
2       blb     b.pdf     jquery
-------------------------------
```

using From the above table i am searching a skill from resume,skill field get the user id. Is it possible to search this way if yes tell how to solve this one OR give the suggestion for alternate way to search the key in file.

I am not good at english .If any mistakes are there excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rs = $this->db
      ->distinct()
      ->select('uid')
      ->like('Resume', $searchTerm, 'both')
      ->or_like('skill', $searchTerm, 'both')
      ->get('User')
      ->result_array();
```

Here, `$searchTerm` is the the text searched for.

Comment: hey May I know, what does 'both' parameter do ?

Comment: Thanks for reply.But here resume filed is only the resume path then how to search in that file ?

Comment: You cant search in that file here, It will just search the database.
The `both` parameter appends the `%` sign in both the sides. For eg. `%the_serach_term%`, `LEFT` appends only in the left side like `%the_search_term` similarly 'RIGHT' appends in the right direction like `the_search_term%` @Deepanshu